# Android ActionBar does not show title that was set in code

Tags: java, android, xml

First, I know there are a lot of SO that address similar issues. I've scoured them all, and none of the provided answers are helping to solve my issue.

I cannot get the title (or back button) to appear on my `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` component. No matter what I've tried.

I have an Android activity that that looks like (*my_activity.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="infos" type="com.mycompany.orm.adapters.ListViewAdapter"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/buttonBackground"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:logo="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/my_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/windowBackground"
            bind:items="@{infos.list}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

And the activity `onCreate` as (*MyActivity.java*):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle("My Name Here");   // Never shows up
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            actionBar.setTitle("Hello World!");       // Never shows up
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.show();
        }
    }
}
```

But using this code, I only see a blank toolbar. I never see the text (either `My Name Here` or `Hello World!`. However, if I add the line `bind:title="Testing"` to the `Toolbar` element of the XML, I see the title appearing as **Testing**. However, I want to be able to manipulate the look of the toolbar/actionbar, so I would like to be able to do it in code.

Does anyone see where this might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set label in your **AndroidManifest.xml** like that

```
   <activity
        android:name="yourpackagename.Activity"
        android:label="My Name Here"/>
```

Otherwise if you want to set as programmatically

If You using extends AppCompatActivity class use

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("My Name Here");
    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

If You using extends Activity class use

```
  ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
  ab.setTitle("My Name Here");
```

I suggest to try to use above solution its work for me .

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and this worked for me.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(""My Name Here"");
```

Comment: That should be the same as above no? `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); if (actionBar != null) { actionBar.setTitle("Hello World!"); }`

Comment: Are you using the following theme?
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    />

Comment: @Brett: I used the same xml and code and it  displayed "Hello world!"
com.android.support:appcompat-v7 23.0.0,

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine.What i did is just comment the line  "setSupportActionBar(toolbar);" because of this error (java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
).And Theme i used is Theme.AppCompat.Please make sure you use a theme that supports actionbar

Comment: Also what i did to achieve this in a previous project                                            

private Toolbar mToolbar;

mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(albumsList.get(position).getTitle()); // use this line to set your string